# iOS URL Request Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to send data to a PHP web page (which already knows what to do with the receiving URL). Once a specific button is clicked, my app should be sending a URL request, but it isn't. I'm using the "NSURLConnectionDelegate", but I didn't implement any methods, am I conforming to it correctly? I've got the following code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.private.com/recievedata.php?name=%@&address=%@&longitude=%@&latitude=%@",_nameLabel.text,_addressLabel.text,_longitudeLabel.text,_latitudeLabel.text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:temp];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
@end
```

Comment: Why are you so sure it is not doing anything? Are you observering the server for the desired result? If the reason is that you are not receiving any data, that is because you do not have the delegate method implemented that is called when a NSURLRequest resolves.

Comment: And what is that method?

Comment: @ErikDolor and yes I observed that the server did not receive any changes, so I figured something is off.

Comment: You have to be implementing the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol methods.

Comment: @pe60t0 I was looking at Apple's site for it, but it lists so many protocol methods. How do I know which one(s) I need for my case?

Comment: If you implement the delegates they will tell you if you receive anything, if it has failed, an error occurred etc. I don't know in what world you think someone can debug this for you

Comment: Search the internet for a tutorial. This cannot be simply answered. Also look into NSURLSession if you are targeting iOS 7+

Comment: @Vimzy you have assign NSURLConnection to self. Extend the delegate of NSURLConnection in .h file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to get what you need:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    //Handle here
}];
```

This is quite limited in the sense that you cannot cancel this connection and if more sophisticated SSL challenges are needed, it cannot be provided. But seems like this is good enough for you.

---

**Update:** Starting with iOS 9, `NSURLConnection` is deprecated. Instead, use `NSURLSession`. Here is the same as above, implemented with the new API:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                               completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    //Handle here
}] resume];
```

Comment: Your answer is better. I deleted mine

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code instead of **[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];**

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:
[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
    if (error)
    {  
        //error message    
    }
    else
    {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //handle server's response here...

    });
    }
}];
```

Hope it will help you.Thank you.